# Ruby on Rails 6 jquery and ajax dynamic form CRUD

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a problem in Rails 6. I have 3 models user, character and ability that have associations between them: 
User can have many characters, character belongs to user, character can have many abilities, ability belongs to character. My goal is to add jquery and ajax that I can create, modify or delete character abilities from character show page. Here is my abilities_controller.rb:

```
class AbilitiesController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @abilities = Ability.all
      end

      def show
      end

      def new
        @ability = Ability.new
      end

      def edit
      end


      def create
        @character = Character.find(params[:character_id])
        @ability = @character.ability.build(ability_params)


        respond_to do |format|
          if @ability.save
            format.js
            format.html { redirect_to @ability, notice: 'Ability was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @ability }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @ability.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @ability.update(ability_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @ability, notice: 'Ability was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @ability }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @ability.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @ability.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to abilities_url, notice: 'Ability was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end
      private

      private
      def ability_params
        params.require(:ability).permit(:name, :value, :picture)
      end
    end
```

Character show page:

```
<h1 align="center"><%= @character.name %></h1>
<hr />
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-2 offset-1 card-img-top card card-body bg-light mx-auto colsize" align="center">
    <% if @character.image.attached? %>
      <%= image_tag(@character.image, size: '120x120') %>
    <% else %>
      <small>No image</small>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8 card card-body bg-light mx-auto" >
    <p>Listing character attributes:</p>

    <div class="row ">
      <% @character.abilities.each do |ability| %>
        <div class="col-md-8  ">
          <div class="card" style="width: 132px;">
            <% if ability.picture.attached? %>
              <%= image_tag(ability.picture, size: '130x130') %>
            <% else %>
              <small>No image</small>
            <% end %>
              <p class="mx-auto"><%= ability.name %>: <%= ability.value %></p>
              <%= link_to 'Edit Ability', new_ability_path, remote: true, class:"btn btn-primary" %>
              <%= link_to 'Delete Ability', new_ability_path, remote: true, class:"btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div id="new-ability" class="pt-2 pb-2">
      <%= link_to 'New Ability', new_ability_path, remote: true, class:"btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <p>
      <small>Created by: <%= @character.user.username.capitalize %>, <%= time_ago_in_words(@character.created_at) %> ago</small>
    </p>
    <div>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to 'Back', characters_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>
        <%if current_user && current_user == @character.user %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_character_path(@character), class: "btn btn-warning" %></td>
          <td><%= link_to "Delete this character", character_path(@character), method: :delete,
                                            data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete?" },
                                            class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>
          </td>
        <%end%>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-11 card card-body bg-light mx-auto mt-3">
      <% if @character.description %>
        <p class="biography-title"><%=@character.name.capitalize%>'s Biography</p>
        <p><%=@character.description%></p>
      <%end%>
    <div/>
</div>
```

Abilities/view/new.js.erb

```
$('#new-ability a').hide().parent().append("<%= j render 'form', ability: @ability %>");
```

Abilities/view/new.html.erb

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

Abilities/view/create.js.erb

```
$('new-ability form').remove();
$('new-ability a').show
```

Abilities/view/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: ability) do |form| %>
  <% if ability.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(ability.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this ability from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% ability.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="row mx-auto pt-2">
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :name %>
      <%= form.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :value %>
      <%= form.text_field :value %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :picture %>
      <%= form.file_field :picture %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= form.submit %>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

And for last characters_controller.rb

```
class CharactersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :index]
  before_action :set_character, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :require_same_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @characters = Character.order(:name).page(params[:page]).per(3)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @character = Character.new
  end

  def edit

  end

  def create
    @character = Character.new(character_params)
    @character.user = current_user

    if @character.save
      flash[:success] = "Character was created successfully!"
      redirect_to character_path(@character)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @character.update(character_params)
      flash[:success] = "Character was updated successfully!"
      redirect_to character_path(@character)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @character.destroy
    flash[:danger] = "Character was deleted successfully"
    redirect_to characters_path
  end

  private

    def set_character
      @character = Character.find(params[:id])
    end

    def character_params
      params.require(:character).permit(:name, :image, :description, abilities_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :character_id, :name, :value, :picture])
    end

    def require_same_user
      if current_user != @character.user
        redirect_to characters_path
      end
    end
end
```

My code is public in git repository: https://github.com/djuks/rpg-game-editor/tree/ajax-devise_controllers-tests
If anyone have possible solution I will be grateful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is it you are having difficulties with?

Comment: I'm new to jquery and ajax, but nothing is working except form I cant add new ability to character i get this error in terminal:ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Character without an ID):
  
app/controllers/abilities_controller.rb:21:in `create'

Comment: So in the error code you've pasted there, there is a number after the file name. That's the line of code that;s causing the problem. So it looks like params[character_id] is nil which would make sense as you haven't passed the character_id in the form or used a nested route for the form. I would suggest you get the form working in a traditional HTML request way first and then introduce the AJAX requests next.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have found all of my errors. The main one is that I used nested routes I didn't provide params to controller.